# Why doesn't the storyboard reflect the text attributes I've set to a UILabel using the attributes inspector panel?

Tags: text, attributes, nsstring, uilabel, inspector

I have a UILabel on the storyboard.  The default text reads "Label".  I then go to the attributes inspector and select the Attributed text style.  When I click on the Text field I am presented with several fonts to choose from in a new window.  I see that the default text in this case has been set to Helvetica size 17.0.  When looking through the fonts presented I decide to use one called ORC A Std.  This is part of the fixed width family.

Since I want to use this font, I go back into my attributes inspector and change the word Label to 500.  With it highlighted I change the font to ORC A Std.

My text that did read Label (in Helvetica) now reads 500 (in ORC A Std).  Excellent.  That's what I want.  Everything is how I want in the attributes inspector panel.

Unfortunately My label on the storyboard has changed from Label (in Helvetica) to 500 (in Helvetica).  Why doesn't it display as the font ORC A std?  I then double click directly on the label to change the text to something else.  When I click on it to edit it, it shows 500 (in ORC A Std).  I change it to say 750 (it's still in ORC A Std).  When I'm done editing it, I click off of it and it now reads 750 (in Helvetica).

Why can't I use the font ORC A Std on my label?

Comment: I realized that when I'm clicking the through the fonts in the text window I can have a preview of the text.  At the top of the window it says the name of the font written in it's font.  When I click on each font it changes.  However When I click on ORC A Std and several around it previews the word Helvetica (written in Helvetica).  However if I double click on the on the font it will read the font name I click on (written in the appropriate font name).  Maybe there is a glitch in my fonts.  If so what should I do?

Comment: I'm running Xcode version 4.6.2 on the latest version of Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug, it also happens to me. I read there's tons of bugs regarding attributed text and Xcode and some of them are already fixed on Xcode 5 and iOS7 SDK. To be sure that's going to be taken care of, please report it to Apple.

For now programmatically change the font and that should work.