# Why attributed string doesn't show on storyboard as well as in App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have simple UILabel which I set an attributed string using Attributes Inspector.

However, the attributed string doesn't reflect its attributes on storyboard as well as in App.

It looks like I didn't nothing, the string is still plain, expect in the Attribute Inspector.

To illustrate the question better, here are two screenshots:

[image: Attributed string in Inspector]

[image: How it actually looks like in storyboard and app]

Comment: check this answer:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031623/how-can-i-use-attributedtext-in-uilabel][1].
might be a duplication.

Comment: @AmirBareket This is not the same question, I was asking about do this in storyboard instead of programmatically.

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't the storyboard reflect the text attributes I've set to a UILabel using the attributes inspector panel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411198/why-doesnt-the-storyboard-reflect-the-text-attributes-ive-set-to-a-uilabel-usi)